# Unity fog clipping

Tags: unity-game-engine

This would seem rather simple but I'm trying to do fog in unity to cut out the distance items, and

[image]

Settings (from Javascript but same idea, left commented out portions for context, Achdus is part of the library, main point is the clipping plane)

```c#
UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fog = true
//UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fogMode = UnityEngine.FogMode.Linear
UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fogColor = new UnityEngine.Color(0.2,0.2,0.2)
UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fogMode = UnityEngine.FogMode.ExponentialSquared
//UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fogMode = UnityEngine.FogMode.Exponential
UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fogStartDistance = 40
UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fogEndDistance = 79
UnityEngine.RenderSettings.fogDensity = .05
UnityEngine.Camera.main.farClipPlane = 
Achdus.Yaakov.mainCoby.shneeuh.farClipPlan = 120
```

It would seem like it should be a simple feature to cut out the fog in the distance?

Tried using kinofog
but I got these errors (after applying cubemap texture to camera)

[image]

How can I clip out distant objects such that the clipping isn't so sharp, and the intensity of the fog isn't cutting it out?

Comment: Isn't fogStartDistance and fogEndDistance only works in linear fog mode?

Comment: @HardcoreGamer yes exactly `The starting distance of linear fog. Fog start and end distances are used by Linear fog mode.`

Comment: Just wondering, your fog mode was set to UnityEngine.FogMode.ExponentialSquared

Comment: I don't know `kinofog` but it seems you have to use a very specific material with a specific shader on it .. the material you used doesn't use the correct shader => the shader references the code is trying to set don't exist

Comment: @HardcoreGamer note that I am not the asker of the question ;) I was just confirming your comment ;)

Comment: @derHugo lol, silly me

Comment: @HardcoreGamer yes `left commented out portions for context` includes leaving the far clipping etc. even tho its no longer needed, but its the same result anyways